# Calculate number of words of length $n$ formed from $\{a, b, c, d\}$ that begin and end with $a$ in which adjacent letters are not the same

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have a problem with following task: I have a set of letters $\{a,b,c,d\}$
I need to calculate number of words with length $n$ that start and end with $a$ and there are no words with same letters next to each other ie $aa$; $bb$ etc. 
I can't come up with recurrence for this one. I will be very glad for help.

Comment: from your description it sounds infinite? for example abcabcabcabc....

Comment: I think OP means how many words for a fixed length n (as they mention finding a recurrence)

Comment: Sorry they should have finite lenght. Let say $n$, I will fix it.

Comment: so it looks forwards backwards symmetric so if you calculate all that start with a, its the same as all that ends with a. though you have to make sure you don't double count those that start and end with a.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easier to drop the condition that the words end in $a$, for now.

Then it is easy to see that the number of words of length $n$ meeting your conditions is $3^{n-1}$ (there are three choices for every slot other than the first).

Now, let us try to work in the condition that the words end in $a$.

Let $A_n$ be the number of words which pass all your conditions.

Let $B_n,C_n,D_n$ be the numbers which pass all the conditions except that they end in $b,c,d$ respectively.  We know that $$A_n+B_n+C_n +D_n=3^{n-1}$$

Recursively we have $$A_n=B_{n-1}+C_{n-1}+D_{n-1}=3^{n-2}-A_{n-1}$$

Thus we have the recursion $$A_n+A_{n-1}=3^{n-2}$$

Examples:  $A_1=1,A_2=0, A_3=3,\cdots$.

We can solve this to get, for $n>1$, $$A_n=\frac {\left(3^{n-1}+3\times (-1)^{n-1}\right)}4$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate also how you get explicit formula? I know method $A_n=q^n$ and calculate it's root but it doesn't seems to work here.

Comment: Ah, in truth I wrote out the first 20 terms and matched it to an exponential.  Perhaps not the most enlightening of methods.  Give me a minute, I'll try for a better explanation.

Comment: Ok:  (sketch).  We have $A_n=3^{n-2}-A_{n-1}=3^{n-2}-3^{n-3}+A_{n-2}$ and so on, yielding $A_n$ as a partial sum for the geometric series with ratio $-3$.  The formula is then just the closed form for that geometric series.